# Annotate using primary key in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Consider a model with some stuff and a method property:

```
class MyModel(models.model):
    blah blah 

    @property
    def func(self):
        blah blah
```

Suppose now I want to annotate MyModel objects with the value of the function:
`MyModel.objects.annotate(func_value=MyModel.objects.get(pk=Subquery(OuterRef('pk'))).func)`
but this throws the following error: OuterRef object has no attribute 'clone'.

How do I properly annotate the function values to the query set?